# What is the numerator of the original fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The numerator and the denominator of a positive fraction are in the ration $1/5$. A new fraction is formed by subtracting 2 from the numerator and adding 5 to the denominator. The difference between original and new fraction is $1/10$. What is the numerator of the original fraction?

Answer (score 2):

You are are given an original fraction of the form $\frac{p}{q}$.

You are told that $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{1}{5}$ (*numerator and denominator are in the ratio $1/5$*)

Furthermore, you are told that $\frac{p}{q}-\frac{p-2}{q+5}=\frac{1}{10}$ (*difference between original fraction and new fraction is $1/10$ where the new fraction is formed by subtracting $2$ from the numerator and adding $5$ to the denominator of the original fraction*)

Continue by trying to express everything in terms of $p$ and only $p$.

---

First line tells us that $q=5p$.

Using this information in the second line, this tells us:

$\frac{p}{5p}-\frac{p-2}{5p+5}=\frac{1}{10}$

Simplifying, moving the left fraction to the other side, and flipping signs

$\frac{p-2}{5p+5}=\frac{1}{10}$

Continue with algebraic simplifications, eventually arriving at a value for $p$

> $10p-20=5p+5\implies 5p=25\implies p=5$

Answer (score 0):

You could start by thinking of the fraction as $\frac {a} {b}$. So the new fraction formed by subtracting 2 from the numerator and adding 5 to the denominator is $\frac {(a-2)}{(b+5)}$. So you have two equations: 
$\frac {a}{b} = \frac {1}{5} $ and 
 $\frac{a}{b} - \frac{(a-2)}{(b+5)} = \frac{1}{10}$ 
solving these equations should give you the answer.

Comment: The added spoiler tag and answer within the spoiler tag is incorrect.  Check your arithmetic or see my answer above.  (*If it were $a=2$ then the new fraction formed would equal zero and you arrive at a contradiction that $\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{10}$*)

Comment: yes..  i removed the spoiler..but in your answer, there is a typo in the denominator. It should be (p-2)/(5p+5) = 1/10 which gives p=5